# RazorPages Post handler mechanism not executed due to Javascript interception

Tags: jquery, confirm, razor-pages

I'm [implementing an example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio) based on `EF Core` and `RazorPages` for performing simple CRUD.

Now specifically the 2nd page (*Index.cshtml*) representing the "List" view. Each row contains a `button` element for deletion.

Snippet from `Products.cshtml`

```
<form method="POST">

    @foreach(var product in Model.Products) {
        <button type="submit" asp-page-handler="delete" asp-route-id="@product.Id">delete</button>
        <!-- the one below doesn't work with my custom Javascript -->
        <!-- <button data-confirm type="submit" asp-page-handler="delete" asp-route-id="@product.Id">delete</button> -->
    }

</form>
```

Snippet from `Products.cshtml.cs`

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostDeleteAsync(int id)
{
    var product = await _db.Products.FindAsync(id);

    if (product != null)
    {
        //_db.Products.Remove(product);
        //await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    return RedirectToPage();
}
```

**Up to this point it works. I can click the delete button and I see a successful redirect back to the page.**

Now I want to add a custom confirmation functionality using Javscript. I can use jQuery in this context so I'm basically intercepting all `data-confirm` attributes buttons and prevent the default action so I can submit only if the user confirms.

```
$('button[data-confirm]').each(function() {
     var currentElement = this;
     var currentForm = currentElement.form;
     $(currentElement).click(function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         var confirmValue = $(currentElement).attr('data-confirm');
         var confirmText = confirmValue ? confirmValue : 'Are you sure?';

         bootbox.confirm(confirmText, function (result) {
             if (result) {
                 currentForm.submit();
             }
         });
    });        
});
```

With my new functionality the `RazorPage` mechanism doesn't call `OnPostDeleteAsync`... How should I submit the form "manually" to comply with RazorPages submits?

Comment: What do you see in the browser developper tools (F12 > Network tab) when the `RedirectToPage` is executed?

Comment: I can see I made a mistake and that it doesn't enter the `OnPostDeleteAsync` handler. The network tab shows a `500` error on `Products`. Without my `data-confirm` mechanism RazorPages posts to `Products?id=11&handler=delete` (so with my mechanism the querystring part is not included). I guess RazorPages have a custom clientside mechanism that transforms the `asp-` attributes into a request. So essentially my question doesn't change...

Comment: Can you show the complete view and how the current form relate to the delete button please?

Comment: I actually left that out for brevity, but I put it back.

Comment: I didn't look at the generated source properly. The button actually contains a `formaction` attribute which I can use to alter the form action before submitting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically had to account for the generated `formaction` attribute on the `button` element. Setting this value as the form action made it work.

```
$('button[data-confirm]').each(function() {
    var currentElement = this;
    var currentForm = currentElement.form;
    $(currentElement).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var confirmValue = $(currentElement).attr('data-confirm');
        var confirmText = confirmValue ? confirmValue : 'Are you sure?';
        var formAction = $(currentElement).attr('formaction');   //ADDED THIS LINE

        bootbox.confirm(confirmText, function (result) {
            if (result) {
                currentForm.action = formAction;                 //ADDED THIS LINE
                currentForm.submit();
            }
        });
    });        
});
```